# Flutter dependecies error when executing app

Tags: flutter

I'm migrating my app to Android 12 and I've some problems with dependencies and versions. The app worked well until now. I get this error when I try to execute it.

../../../AppData/Local/Android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-13.1.0/lib/src/messaging.dart:128:22: Error: A value of type 'bool' can't be returned from a function with return type 'Future'.

- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return _delegate.isSupported();
  ^
  ../../../AppData/Local/Android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-13.1.0/lib/src/messaging.dart:238:22: Error: The method 'setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseMessagingPlatform'.
- 'FirebaseMessagingPlatform' is from 'package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_messaging.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.1/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_messaging.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery'.
  return _delegate.setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery(enabled);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../AppData/Local/Android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
  FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Here is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: atgapp
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.12.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.7
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.6
  file_picker: ^5.2.5
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  image_picker:
  firebase_messaging: ^13.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
  cloud_functions: ^3.2.8
  firebase_auth: ^3.11.2
  animated_splash_screen: ^1.2.0
  diacritic: ^0.1.3
  restart_app: ^1.1.0
  #firebase_messaging: ^10.0.0
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_messaging_platform_interface: 3.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `pubspec.lock` and run again.

Comment: The error continue appearing.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I've solved searching all firebase related dependencies (core, messaging, etc.) in pubdev and replacing in my Manifest the version to the last published.
Now, the app seems to work as expected.